# About the ``recent" paper by Razborov in the Annals of Mathematics

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, arithmetic-circuits, circuit-families, circuit-depth

Recently this paper on complexity theory was published at the Annals of Mathematics by Razborov, http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2015/181-2/p01. Curiously this seems to have been submitted to the journal 12 years ago!

I was wondering if by now this work has already gone into some textbook or has it gotten improved or if there are already pedagogic expositions available for this? It would be helpful to get such references if they exist!

Comment: Please state exactly which result you want an exposition for. See Jan Krajicek's book "Forcing with Random Variables", chapters related to proof complexity generators. Razborov himself has links to some good surveys on the topic on his homepage.

Comment: ^These subsume this particular paper?